# Checking availability of a large amount of applications in Microsoft store

Tags: api, windows-store-apps, windows-store

My goal is to check for around 800 tools whether they are available in the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/apps/windows) or not. Is there a way to query the tools available in the Microsoft Store via API or something similar?
I am grateful for any suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a scripting language like PowerShell or BASH or pick your favorite to automate your 800 queries of the Microsoft Store web interface with the respective query at the following URI in the PowerShell example:

```
$region = 'en-us'  # Variable to represent your region.
$keywords = 'Hello+World' # Tool name here, keywords separated by plus
$query = 'https://www.microsoft.com/{0}/search/explore?q={1}' -f $region, 
$keywords
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $query
# Parse the response HTML, e.g. $response.Links | Out-Gridview
```

Cheers,
CarnegieJ